# Safeguard from Locked Access DB

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010, locked-files

I'm developing a windows form application on Visual Studio 2012 in C# using a MS-Access 2010 DB in shared mode and due to that exactly, running both the program and the DB file at the same time, both the program and the DB file crashed which ended up making the lockfile not deleting itself after closing the database file (not even after I restarted the computer, and yeah I was the only one using the file and with all rights(read,write) I'm sure of that since it was one I copied just to test the program and ran a lot of tests before that happened).

I solved the issue by making a copy of the DB into elsewhere and deleting both the lock and the database being locked, but I want to avoid that for the user of my application in case he decides to check the database directly while using the program or such.

So any suggestions on how to safeguard from that issue?

Comment: The lock file (`.laccdb` file) is normally deleted after the last active user closes their database connection, but leftover lock files are usually not a problem. The next time ACE hits the database file it just uses the existing lock file instead of creating a new one. Were you unable to access the database after the crash and before you removed the old lock file?

Comment: Gord is right. I have seen where lock files do cause problems but that was only in a networked, multi-user environment. If this is really a big problem you might consider using SQL Server Express instead.

Comment: @GordThompson I could open it but when I'd try to compact and repair i'd come up with an error saying the administrator of the pc481 (my pc) was using the Database and no matter how many times I'd open and close it the lock file remained there. Even after I restarted the computer.